# How to call a None output from Tkinter Text Widget as an IF parameter?

Tags: python, tkinter, adb

I'm currently developing a tkinter app for scanning devices using adb as my final project. The program will read the result of the device and insert it inside a Text widget. The problem is, if there's no device connected, there's no output inside the text widget (just blank text widget). I'm trying to use the blank text widget as my IF operator but it doesn't seem to work?

```py
import os

import tkinter as tk

os.chdir(path)
self.devices = os.popen("adb devices").read().split('\n', 1)[1].split("device")[0].strip()
models = os.popen("adb shell getprop ro.product.model").read()
connect = os.popen("adb connect " + str(self.devices)).read()

devicelist = tk.Text(self, height=2, pady=10)
devicelist.insert(1.0, connect + models)

for self.devices in connect:
    if self.devices is None:
        notFound = tk.Label(self,text="Device not found or not connected")
        notFound.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        return

    else:
        devicelist.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=140)
        devicelist.configure(state="disabled")
        devicelist.tag_configure("center", justify="center")
        devicelist.tag_add("center", 1.0, "end")
```

[image: here is the look of the program if it successfully detected the device]
[image: and this is when it doesn't detect any]

the first picture show how the program looks if it detected a device. and the second one when it fails to do so.

what I'm trying to do is giving an error message if the program didn't detect any connected device.
I'm sorry if it still unclear, I'm really new to python.

Comment: have you checked what self.devices contains? If it seems to be None, does the if statment becomes true? If I remember right there was a diffrence between `is None` and `== None`. Does that 'not-devices' cast to false? than u could simply use `if self.devices:`

Comment: btw. just a to avoid confusion, from the context I think the `if` checks a specifig (single) device. You should name the variable `device` instead of `devices`.

Comment: I just notized you overwrite `self.devices` in the for loop, thats probably not what you wan't to do...

Comment: @sarbot yes I already checked. currently it is empty because I didn't connect my device. but, it works just fine if I connected my device and the text widget will give me the self.devices output. I've tried both  `is None` and `== None`, and none of it works. the same goes with `if self.devices`.

Comment: can you make clearify "dont work"? what do you expect? what do you get? You loop over the connections... "The problem is, if there's no device connected, there's no output inside the text widget". If your variable `connections` if empty, the loop does not run and the `if self.devices` is never called. So the Device not found message is not printed. If you want to execute the loop in the case  `self.devices = None` and `connect = []`, you should add `None` to the empty list.. 
an empty list `[ ]` is not the same as None in a list `[ None ]`.

Comment: It may help me to understand if you give me some examples for the content of `connect` and `self.devices`, for the working and the problematic situation..

Comment: @sarbot ah yeah, sorry about that. I'm really new to python and not sure what the real problem is :D  I think the reason is as you were saying that `the loop does not run` because the variable is empty. So what I'm trying to do is `scan for connected device, if there's a connected device the progam will continue to run. if there's none, the program will give you an error message`. I hope that will make it clear

Comment: I'll try to add some screenshot so it's easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use try: and except: insted of if and else

```
import os

import tkinter as tk

os.chdir(path)
self.devices = os.popen("adb devices").read().split('\n', 1)[1].split("device")[0].strip()
models = os.popen("adb shell getprop ro.product.model").read()
connect = os.popen("adb connect " + str(self.devices)).read()

devicelist = tk.Text(self, height=2, pady=10)
devicelist.insert(1.0, connect + models)

for self.devices in connect:
  try:
    self.devices
    devicelist.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=140)
    devicelist.configure(state="disabled")
    devicelist.tag_configure("center", justify="center")
    devicelist.tag_add("center", 1.0, "end")
  except:
    notFound = tk.Label(self,text="Device not found or not connected")
    notFound.pack(side="top", fill="x")
    return
```

probably this can help you

Comment: Thank yout for your input, but it still doesn't give me the output of `except`. and the problem remains the same as `if` and `else`

Comment: if it doesn't give the output of except: then your self.devices in try: is ok

Comment: what I'm trying to do is giving an error message if the program fails to detect any connected device. sorry if I'm being unlcear.